# HTML5 <video> using navigator.getUserMedia() in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, webkit, html5-video, video-processing, getusermedia

I've been using the HTML5 `<video>` element and it is working in both Chrome and Firefox, however, for some reason it doesn't work **when I load it from a file locally** in chrome however it will work in firefox.

Example: http://codepen.io/asolar/pen/BoyPxZ

Can anyone tell me why this doesn't work in *chrome* and does work in *firefox* when its a file?  Is there some type of security setting I can change in chrome?

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

  <div>
    <video id="camera" width="640" height="480" autoplay style="display: inline;"></video>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">

  window.addEventListener('load', function() {Video();}, false);

  // Setup the Audio and Video
  function Video() {

    navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;
    window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window.msURL || window.mozURL;

    var constraints = {video: true, audio: true};
    navigator.getUserMedia(constraints, (function(stream)
    {
      PlayVideo(stream);
      //PlayAudio(stream);
    }),
    (function(err) {
      console.log("The following error occured: " + err.name);
    }));
  }

  // play the <video>
  function PlayVideo(stream) {
    video = document.querySelector('video');
    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
    video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
      video.play();
    }
  }

  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can blame Goolge for this:
getUserMedia() will throw an error with http:// in Chrome 47 and above (due to deprecation in Chrome).
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=520765